# How to get "linked issue field" value in a JIRA Screen?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have a linked issue field in one of my screens. How can I retrieve the value entered in that ?
Ive tried

```
CustomFieldManager  custFieldMgr = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager();
CustomField cfo_linkedissue = custFieldMgr.getCustomFieldObjectByName("issuelinks");
```

but cfo_linkedissue  returns null , also tried with issuelinks-issues-textarea and issuelinks-issues-multi-select but returning null even then.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue links is not custom field. You need to use [IssueLinkManager](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/link/IssueLinkManager.html) for get [IssueLink](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/link/IssueLink.html).

```
IssueLinkManager linkMgr = ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager();
List<IssueLink> outwardLinks = linkMgr.getOutwardLinks(issue.id);
List<IssueLink> inwardLinks = linkMgr.getInwardLinks(issue.id);
```